# How to store go dependencies?

Tags: go, artifactory

I am using [GoDep](https://github.com/tools/godep) to resolve a project dependencies.
My problem is that repositories for dependencies maight be removed and my project wouldn't build.

I am trying to find any solution to store dependencies at Artifactory or another solution.

Please advice.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so GoDeps may be the standard way of doing this, but I usually found it a bit complicated. In my opinion, use a Makefile which sets a custom GoPath and just include dependencies with your code (remove their .git folder). This way the version freezes and no one needs to do a `godep restore` or something similar.

You can make recipes like `make deploy` that builds your code, runs GoFmt, cleans the pkg files, installs it to your custom GoPath `bin/` and then you just go and run the binary.

You can have another one like `make install` that will install any missing dependencies.

I've managed to create a watch using this on my Makefile to keep on looking for changes on a linux based system using `inotify-tools` and call rebuild.

Internally all commands will be using standard `go` commands but you'll get rid of the GoDeps and maintaining JSON. To upgrade a dependency, it may be a bit of a problem as you'd have to manually copy the whole directory into your custom path and remove the .git/ folder.

Our company uses this method and seems to work quite nice for us.

Plus this method basically gets you away the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/repoName/` kind of paths.

If i seem unclear, let me know, I'll add a gist on github.

Comment: Alternatively, just use govendor (https://github.com/kardianos/govendor) which does all of that for you without needing to set a custom `$GOPATH` in your makefile (which breaks casual usages of `go build` and similar, and frankly, `make` is slow as hell for things like that).  Govendor will store your deps in `<project root>/vendor`, which checks them in with your code, allowing reliable builds.  As long as you're using Go 1.6 (or 1.5 and set the vendoring envvar), you don't need a custom `$GOPATH` at all, since the `go` tool automatically `prefers` the `/vendor` folder.

Comment: Ahh stackoverflow.. You teach me something new everyday! Thanks, I'll give that a look.

Comment: Don't don't don't check in binary files with your source code into your **source** control. Don't.

Comment: Never asked to check in binary. Only the source code for dependencies. The build handles binary creation on first run. We add `bin/` to `.gitignore`.